# How to Save as in 1 GeoTIFF file the hillshade raster and colored raster layer in QGIS 3.4.4?

Tags: raster, color, hillshade, qgis-3

I have a raster GeoTIFF of western Mediterranean sea and i want to apply the hillshade model with colors as the tutorial explains ([Create great looking hillshaded maps in QGIS](https://ieqgis.wordpress.com/2015/04/04/create-great-looking-topographic-maps-in-qgis-2/)). After i finished my tests with hillshade and colors i want to save as 1 raster file both of layers ?

[image]

Can you help me ?

Comment: You have two raster files with elevations stored in the pixel values. The DEM is coloured with a single band custom pseudocolor scale. The Hillshade is coloured with a single band custom gray scale. Also you are handling the transparency between them. And you have a great map! But I thnk that you can't have all that properties in a single raster file.

Comment: The [ahmadhmb's answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/310623/how-to-save-as-in-1-geotiff-file-the-hillshade-raster-and-colored-raster-layer-i/310625#310625) can be a good apprach. There are others, but all of them involve saving the values of the colours, as paletted uniqe values for the pixels, or as their corresponding intensity of red, green and blue in three bands. You would lose the elevations by doing so.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your purpose is for visualization as a rendered image, then you can use `Export Map to Image` from `File -> Import/Export -> Export Map to Image`

[image]

Then, use `Calculate from Layer` and select the hillshade, and check `Save world file` if you want to keep the georeference of the image:

[image]

Comment: @Iven Pepa Bear in mind the exported image will not have the same attributes as the original ones, i.e. definition & spatial resolution. This is a rendering of the map view based on specified scale and resolution/definition, for which you'll need to play around a bit to calculate the correct values for your needs.

Comment: @GabrielC. Thanks for adding more information about the rendered image. It is really helpful.

Comment: Yes thats what i want just, dont need data at this point just for design. Before was trying with merge raster and converting them from float64 to byte but after using merge rasters the colors was different from the layer pseudocolor scale and couldn't finish my work. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Try make a print layout and then save export it as tif.
Im